# How do I get to the courtyard?

Tags: another-code-recollection

At the start of Chapter 4 of *Another Code: Recollection*, you're required to find the Silver Bird Key in order to open the Silver Bird Room, where D is. Marie's letter with the Woman Doll inside the East Wing Bedroom from earlier on in the game reveals that the key is in the fountain in the courtyard.

There are [various guides online](https://gamerant.com/another-code-recollection-how-to-get-silver-sprout-key-fountain-puzzle-guide/) explaining how to get the key once you reach the courtyard, but I don't understand *how* you're supposed to reach the courtyard in the first place. All the guide says is that it

> can be accessed by going through the large white back doors at the Mansion's entrance.

However, when I try to do exactly that, Ashley says "I don't want to see my dad right now" and refuses to go through them. I can't go out the front doors either, as Ashley refuses to leave the mansion. I don't see any other "large white back doors" in the foyer, or anywhere else, for that matter.

So what the heck am I supposed to do here? **How do I get to the courtyard?**

Comment: For some reason, GameFAQs doesn't give Recollection a separate guides section, and Silver Bird Room only is mentioned in Trace Memory Chapter 1: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/426391-another-code-recollection/faqs/44169 ... Did you typo Chapter 1 as Chapter 4?

Comment: @Malady No. That walkthrough is only applicable to the original DS game, the Switch remake in *Recollection* features different puzzles and puts things in a different order.

Comment: It seems like you might need to examine the Silver Bird Room door again? https://youtu.be/wwSO948klPk?list=PLjen7U7PlzEqRAMD2ad2-_mfKHPOsKoLR&t=5464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Malady stated in a comment, you need to interact with the door to the Silver Bird Room to trigger a cutscene. After that cutscene has been triggered, you can then try the "large white back doors" in the foyer, and Ashley's dialogue will change to

> I don't really want to see Dad right now, but... I guess I don't have much choice.

Interact with the doors again and you'll finally step out into the courtyard in search of the Silver Bird Key.